# Add a field to a work item in tfs 2017

Tags: tfs

I have a request to add a new field to a work item and we are using TFS 2017.  My organization has done this before in previous versions of TFS.  However, I remember customizing any process template to add new fields causes headaches when upgrading to the next version of TFS.

My question is if this is still a concern?  If so, is there a work-around for this issue?

Thanks!

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you would have the same procedure if you want to upgrade a on-premises TFS with customizations.

So, before you customize, you should understand which customizations support an easy update path and which do not.

**Recommended practices**:

- Identify the best options for customizing WITs that support your
  tracking requirements. When you change objects that track work items,
  you should identify how these changes will affect existing and future
  team projects.
- Put processes and all XML definition files under version control. Do
  not deploy objects that you define but have not stored in a
  repository.
- Test your customized objects just as you would test your software.
- Minimize the number of custom fields that you introduce. Minimize the
  number of fields that you make reportable.

Please refer to the link below for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/on-premises-xml-process-model#before-you-customize